# SwiftUI Text View does not show non-displayable characters

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have Swift code which parses an LLDP (link layer discovery protocol) frame, including a field that can be arbitrarily vendor-defined.  Sometimes it's a String.  Sometimes its an arbitrary data structure.

Here's how I take the data and force it into a String with .utf8 encoding.

```
        let ouiString = String(data: data[data.startIndex + 6 ..< data.startIndex + 2 + tlvLength], encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
```

Here's the resulting data structure (part of an enumeration with an associated value).  "ouiString" above is now in the "info: String" field at the end.

```
case ouiSpecific(oui: String, subType: Int, info: String)
```

Here's how I generate a description:

```
    case .ouiSpecific(let oui, let subType, let info):
        return "OUI \(oui) subType \(subType) \(info)"
```

Here's an example of the description where the original data was not a String. The non-displayable characters are shown in a way I find acceptable.

```
(lldb) po value.description
"OUI 00:12:0f subType 5 \0\u{11}\0\u{11}\0\u{11}\0\u{11}\0\u{11}"
```

Here's how I try to display it in a SwiftUI List:

```
        List(lldp.values, id: \.self) { value in
            Text(value.description)
        }
```

And here's an image of the resulting display in SwiftUI.  The info field with all the escaped non-displayable characters are not shown.

[image: SwiftUI List Output]

How can I display the field in a SwiftUI Text View with the non-displayable characters escaped like in the "po" output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Unicode.Scalar` method `escaped(asASCII: Bool)`  to convert unprintable characters to string:

```
func escaped(asASCII forceASCII: Bool) -> String
```

> Scalar values representing characters that are normally unprintable or
>   that otherwise require escaping are escaped with a backslash.

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var asciiEscaped: String {
        unicodeScalars.map{$0.escaped(asASCII: true)}.joined()
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let str = "\0\u{11}\0\u{11}\0\u{11}\0\u{11}\0\u{11}"
print(str.asciiEscaped)
```

This will print:

> \0\u{11}\0\u{11}\0\u{11}\0\u{11}\0\u{11}

Comment: Thank you!  I figured there was an easy function somewhere but never would have thought to look under Unicode.Scalar.